# Significant terms aggregation for arrays in elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, arrays, elasticsearch

I am unable to perform a significant terms aggregation using a field that is an array. My Javascript query looks like this:

```
client.search({
  index: myIndex,
  body: {
    query: {
      terms: {
        myField: ['someuserid']
        // also tried with same result... myField: 'someuserid'
      }
    },
    aggregations: {
      recommendations: {
        significant_terms: {
          field: "myField",
          min_doc_count: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I get this error:

```
(node:13105) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): Error: [illegal_argument_exception] Fielddata is disabled 
on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [myField] in order to 
load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can 
however use significant memory.
```

My mapping looks like this:

```
{
  index: 'myIndex',
  type: 'users',
  body: {
    properties: {
        'myField': []
    }
  }
}
```

I know that I don't need to explicitly map array data types, but I do it so I can easily see what fields I have for a certain `type`. Following the error message I would change my mapping to look like this:

```
...
properties: {
  myField: {
    fielddata: "true"
  }
}
...
```

However, this results in this error:

```
Error: [mapper_parsing_exception] No type specified for field [myField]
```

If I were to then add a type:
    ...
    properties: {
      myField: {
        type: [],
        fielddata: "true"
      }
    }
    ...
I would get this error:

```
[mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for type [[]] declared on field [myField]
```

Currently, the data I am aggregating is from data that is seeded through the Javascript client library completely using the Update API constructed with this:

```
const update = {
    "upsert": {
      "myField": ['myValue']
    },
    "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.myField.add(params.itemField)",
    "params": {
      "itemField": 'itemValue'
    }
  }
};

const req = {
    index: 'myIndex',
    type: 'users',
    id: 'someuserid',
    body: update
}
```

Hits from this query `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myIndex/users/_search?pretty'` would then look like this:

```
...
{
    "_index" : "myIndex",
    "_type" : "users",
    "_id" : "someuserid",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "myField" : [
        "someFieldId1",
        "someFieldId1",
        "someFieldId2"
      ]
    }
  },
...
```

How can I properly perform a significant terms aggregation using a field that is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html

> In Elasticsearch, there is no dedicated array type. Any field can
>   contain zero or more values by default, however, all values in the
>   array must be of the same datatype.

Assuming you are using ElasticSearch 5.x, try to change **type: []** to **type:  "text"** or **type:  "keyword"**

For the difference between the two I would recommend reading this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html

However in your case, since it looks like some kind of id, it likely doesn't need to be analyzed, so I would suggest "keyword" instead of "text".

For previous versions of ES, use "string" instead. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/string.html

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I ended up doing. Yeah, I read that piece of documentation over and over again, but I intuitively thought that adding the type as a text or keyword will make it so that if I were to update the doc, the field will be replaced (not what I want) instead of forming an array and adding to it. I need to look it up some more, but I suppose if I wanted that I would use the index API instead of the update API.

Comment: You can try to use the update API with a script doing 
ctx._source.myField += newValue

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates